# Bluetooth Keyboard for Android

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, circuit

I'm trying to make a bluetooth keyboard(3x4)for Android Phones with the use of any arduino because I'm trying to make that as a Braille keyboard. Is it possible? If it is. What kind of arduino should I use? And any other bluetooth shield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an Arduino uno (or any compatible board) and a bluetooth shield or board for Arduino. You can try out this [bluetooth board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/158) from sparkfun.

This board connects to Arduino via serial. So you can just used the built-in Serial library.

This board also connects easily with Android devices.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I have bought an arduino 328 clonea and a bluetooth shield hoping to make that braille keyboard

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know any sites that have tutorials that can help me?

Comment: You can checkout this presentation of mine, where I talk about different way to make Android and Arduino to talk to each other http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/building-robots-using-arduino-and-android-at-droidcon Also checkout this project of mine, where I control an Arduino robot using Android http://hardwarefun.com/projects/asimi